# Positioning SKSpriteNodes in GameScene

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, ipad

I am having a little bit of trouble positioning two SKSpriteNodes correctly in my GameScene. My nodes appear in the scene, but they are zoomed in and take up most of the entire scene. I would to have the output similar to this:

[image]

Here is my current code:

```
let size = CGRect(x: 100, y:98, width:200, hight:271)
bottomRectangle = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bottomRectangle")

bottomRectangle.zPosition = 3
bottomRectangle.size.height = self.size.height
bottomRectangle.size.width = self.size.width
bottomRectangle.position = CGPoint(x: 200, y:271)
bottomRectangle.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: size)





self.addChild(bottomRectangle)

topRectangle = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "topRectangle")
topRectangle.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: size)
topRectangle.zPosition = 4
topRectangle.size.height = self.size.height
topRectangle.size.width = self.size.width
topRectangle.position = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 98)
self.addChild(topRectangle)
```

Comment: This code does not compile. You are putting inside `bottomRectangle` an `SKSpriteNode` and then a `CGPoint`.

Comment: I have edited and updated my  code.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the size of the scene, because of:

```
self.size.height
```

You have to use you local variable:

```
 size.height
```

Comment: That did help, the rectangles don't take up the entire screen anymore. Both the positions and sizes of the rectangles are still slightly off however. Would setting anchor points or using CGPointZero help get the rectangles in the positions as shown in the picture above? I am also trying to set the rectangles as boundaries as shown in my code above to keep an object from leaving the space in-between the rectangles.

Comment: I think that you have to use something like scale to fill, in case the image has a different size then your declared CGSize

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I have been very busy with work. I appreciate your response. I was using scale to fill but switched over Aspect Fit. I am going to try tinkering around with anchor points for each bar. The bars are blown up out of proportion and the entire bar won't display in the scene.